# Auto login after registration user

Tags: java, spring

Dear fellow programmers,

The context is the next: The user, after completing the registration form and send, be authenticated and redirected to the home page automatically, not having to return to the login form to log in.

The application security is managed by Spring Security.
I'm trying to implement this new function in my application, but it does not work.

I have problem especifcally to inject the authenticationManager in my SpringService, look bellow my code:

Class SignUpMB:

```
@RequestScope
@Component
public class SignUpMB {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SignupService signUpService;

    private User user = new User();
    private ProfileUser profileUser = new ProfileUser();

    private String confirmPw;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        userService.addUser(user, profileUser);


        signUpService.authenticateUserAndSession(user, request);
        return "../index.xhtml";

    }
...
}
```

Class SignupService:

```
@Service
public class SignupService {

    @Autowired
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /*@Autowired
    RequestCache requestCache;*/

    public void authenticateUserAndSession(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = user.getMail();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        request.getSession();

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
        Authentication authenticationUser= authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationUser);

    }

}
```

Now follow the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'signupService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
```

Please, any idea how I can solved it? Thank you so mutch.

Comment: Are there controls to prevent a bot from continuously registering and logging in new users?  Does the initial registration process include some form of 2FA and/or CAPTCHA?

Comment: Andrew, not yet, but in other moment I go make it! Do you have otther sugestion about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `authenticationManagerBean()` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to  manually expose `AuthenticationManager` as a spring bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
}
```

You only can autowire spring managed bean.

Comment: Ohh, It worked for me, and a learned more about the Spring!  thank you so mutch Benjamin!!

Comment: @LeonardoTorres glad to help you out